# NetworkOnMainThreadException raised while parsing JSON with GSON

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a simple activity that sends an email and a password to a server and the server returns the next `JSON`:

```
{
   "token": "mytoken"
}
```

I'm doing the request on a different thread (`AsyncTask`), but my code is throwing the next exception:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:489)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.isDataAvailable(SocketInputBuffer.java:80)
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.IdentityInputStream.available(IdentityInputStream.java:63)
            at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.available(EofSensorInputStream.java:196)
            at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:223)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1300)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1346)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.consumeNonExecutePrefix(JsonReader.java:1582)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:538)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:429)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:806)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:748)
            at com.myapp.evalatuclase.evaluacion.LoginActivity$LoginOperation.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:67)
            at com.myapp.evalatuclase.evaluacion.LoginActivity$LoginOperation.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:47)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code:

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.myapp.evalatuclase.evaluacion;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ingresar);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.matriculaOemail);
                EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email.getText().toString()));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password.getText().toString()));
                new LoginOperation().execute(params);
            }
        });
    }




    private class LoginOperation extends AsyncTask<List<NameValuePair>,Void,Reader>{

        @Override
        protected  Reader doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... params){
            try{
                HttpBasicRequestService http = new HttpBasicRequestService();
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(http.makePost("/auth/login/", "",params[0]));
                return  reader;
            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.d("EVALUA_TU_CLASE", "Error "+ ex.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Reader reader) {
                super.onPostExecute(reader);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Log.d("EVALUA_TU_CLASE", "Creando json");
                LoginJSON token = gson.fromJson(reader,LoginJSON.class); // In this line is where the exception is throwed :C
                Log.d("EVALUA_TU_CLASE", "JSON");
                Log.d("EVALUA_TU_CLASE", token.token);


            //getSharedPreferences("EVALUA_TU_PROFESOR", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        }
    }
}
```

**HttpBasicRequestService.java**

```
package com.myapp.evalatuclase.evaluacion;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class HttpBasicRequestService {

    public InputStream makeGet(String url, String tokenUser) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(Constants.URL_WEB_SERVICE.concat(url));
        getRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "JWT ".concat(tokenUser));
        try {
            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
                return null;
            }
            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
            return getResponseEntity.getContent();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
        }
        return null;
    }


    public InputStream makePost(String url,String tokenUser, List<NameValuePair> params ){
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Constants.URL_WEB_SERVICE.concat(url));
        post.addHeader("Authorization", "JWT ".concat(tokenUser));
        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            Log.e("EVALUA_TU_CLASE", e.toString());
        }
        try {
            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(post);
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
                return null;
            }
            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
            return getResponseEntity.getContent();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            post.abort();
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**LoginJSON.java**

```
package com.myapp.evalatuclase.evaluacion;

public class LoginJSON {

    public String token;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your Reader is a stream reader that's taking data from the network so you either have to read all the data at once or parse the JSON on the thread (best solution).  The stream is opened on the thread, but nothing is actually read until the GSON library starts reading.

Comment: Try to move GSON operations in to doInBackground method and check.

Comment: @DeeV I'll try the second one, let you know in some minutes!

Comment: @DeeV It worked, please write it down as an answer! :D

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres was my comment helpful ?

Comment: @Muthu Yes, basically your comment is the second part of  DeeV's comment and that's what I did.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: @Simon look well at the questions are different